# AWS amplify don't deploy latest commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

How are you.
I am building react.js web application and deploying it on aws amplify.
It was working for more than an year well.
Even yesterday, the 150th build was successed.
But today, when I pushed new commit, Aws amplify don't detect new commit so doesn't deploy.
Because there is nowhere I can deploy custom commit, I don't know how to deploy my last commit.
I don't know if aws amplify service has build limit to 150.
The version already deployed work well.
The problem is just they didn't detect new commit so it doesn't deploy last commit.
Thanks

Comment: Did you check the webhook delivery logs to see if there was issue?  Also, on github you can redeliver the webhook if it was successful.

Comment: there is no webhook. I never set it before but it worked.

Comment: You have a webhook because that is how the amplify service gets notified.  Amplify registers the webhook for you when you authorize access to the repo.

Comment: Try click reconnect branch button in the amplify console.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Try this Reconnect repository button. It worked for me on the same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Reconnecting the repository as suggested by [Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4113382/raj) and also by an AWS engineer [in reply to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/400#issuecomment-585924101) didn't work for me. I'm using GitHub and deleted the webhook created by Amplify on my repo's settings as recommended in the dialogue box for reconnecting the repo.

A solution that did work in my case was to create a webhook on the Amplify settings and use it to manually trigger a build by running the `curl` command provided in the settings on my terminal (see screenshot below by [Michael Hwang](https://michaelihwang.com/)).

[image: Screenshot of webhook settings by Michael Hwang]

This workaround was first suggested by [Arthur Käpp](https://github.com/ArturKp) on the [issue linked above](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/400#issuecomment-582772160) and later by [Chase Logan](https://github.com/cslogan-red) on [a separate GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1140#issuecomment-821522897). I originally came across it in a [helpful blogpost](https://bigendians.com/2021/07/11/manually-trigger-builds-on-aws-amplify/) by [Michael Hwang](https://michaelihwang.com/) which includes the screenshot above.

Comment: In addition, you can add this webhook to Github to guarantee it will deploy on each commit.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well. I think the problem is the build was failing.  So  perhaps check your build logs.
[image]

In my case the problem was the build settings were not filled in.   I was missing `yarn install` from my prebuild and `yarn run build` from build commands in  amplify.yml [image]